# Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/parser' when using Prettier Eslint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I'm getting the following error from Prettier Eslint Output on VSCode when saving the file.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/parser'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\vtnor\.vscode\extensions\rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-0.4.1\dist\extension.js
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
```

My package json is:

```
[...]
"typescript": "^4.2.2",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.16.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.16.1",
"eslint": "^7.21.0",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
[...]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually had this problem the other day; you need to go to your `.eslintrc`
and make sure that the module is there under the `parser` property of the config. Should look something like this in the end:

```
{
  //...

  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],

  //...
}
```

This should cover the essentials regarding dependencies in your linter. Hope it helps.

**Edit**

I checked GitHub for this issue, might not be the same as the one I had, check [this link](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/905) please.

Comment: I tried to add and remove this parser line. Currently I do have this line and I moved it - just in case - to be after extends. Still got the same error.

Comment: This isn't the same error, but I did try to restart my PC. Didn't work.

Comment: not working please let me know if you find any solution @VítorNorton

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. Make sure that you also restart vscode to see the warning disappear.

Answer (score 11):

Had this problem also, I resolved disabling, then reloading and re-enabling ESLint extension of VSCode.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 6):

I discovered that the cause of the error in my case was ESLint itself was throwing an error. I discovered this by looking at the ESLint output in VSCode.  The fix was to update one of my other dependencies (eslint-plugin-import).

Comment: this should be the best answer! I found out that one of the plugins was not loading since it shouldn't be there and the parser was throwing in the Prettier Eslint output but the real issue was found in the Eslint Output

Answer (score 2):

Open VS Code in the correct directory.

Example, we have:

```
/dir1/
/dir1/node_modules
```

In the `dir1` directory
. Right click
. Open with Code

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably that `.eslintrc` is not finding necessary modules because that are in a wrong location. `.eslintrc` needs to have folder `node_modules` right next to it. This can easily be achieved by putting `.eslintrc` into the project folder and creating `package.json` right next to it. Then `node_modules` will also be created in the project folder and the necessary (and installed) modules will be found.

Your project folder should look similar to:

[image: content of project folder]

Answer (score 1):

Installing `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and then reloading VSCode solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps anyone :D

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this with `npm remove @typescript-eslint/parser` && `npm install @typescript-eslint/parser`

Answer (score 0):

I just added the `metro.config.js` (like I did for an other fix for `babel.config.js`) to `.eslintignore`.